# Expected value $<\hat{x}>$ of: $\Phi(x,t)=Ne^{-a[(Mx^2/\hbar)+it]}$ is infinite, why?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

The problem says:

A particle of mass $M$ is described by the wave function:

$$\Phi(x,t)=Ne^{-a[(Mx^2/\hbar)+it]}$$

where a is a positive constant.

Asked to determine such things as the normalization constant $N$, which is quite simple.

However, after requests to obtain the expected value of $<\hat{x}>$, even though I've tried is hand, always came to the integral:

$$<\hat{x}>=cte*\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}y e^{-y^2}dy$$

according to me, the integral can not be calculated with these limits should not be infinite integrla that?

Hoping someone will tell me how to interpret this, or if there is way to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Evidently this is a homework problem.   One way to approach the integral is to look at the symmetry of the integrand.  To get started:  the integrand has two factors.  one of them, $y$, is odd under inversion of the axis.  Once you have the symmetry of the integrand, you can make quick progress with the integral.

Make a sketch of the integrand.  That will help.

Comment: +1, symmetry rules everything around us. One could probably even find the answer by considering the symmetry of the *situation*.

Comment: @Danu That's the best answer!